# Creating floating images loaded d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and trying to load the images dynamically from folder using d3.js based on certain conditions. Code I am using is

```
           var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 150)
            .attr("height", 150)
            .style("border", "1px solid black");


d3.csv("data/Images.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {

        arrFileUrl.push(d['FingerImageName']);
        arrBrightness.push(d['Brightness']);
        arrPattern.push(d['Pattern']);
        arrSize.push(d['Size']);

    });//data


    var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data(arrFileUrl[0]);

    imgs.enter()
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", arrFileUrl[0])
        .attr("x", "20")
        .attr("y", "20")
        .attr("width", "120")
        .attr("height", "120");
```

I want to make these images float around just like bubbles, so that they don't have fix positions. How can I make this?

Comment: May be you can use force layout https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the data binding wrong: if you want one image for each piece of data, use:

```
var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data(arrFileUrl);
```

if you want only the first image, use:

```
var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data( [arrFileUrl[0]] );
```

(the data function always takes an array).

---

This being said, using your `data` object (instead of `arrFileUrl`) would probably be a more sensible choice in the long run. You can access the string name as follows:

```
 .attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) {return d.FingerImageName})
```

To make the images move around, use [Force Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) with

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(data)
    .start()
```

You might need to play with gravity and other coefficients to get the effect you want. In any case, this gives `x` and `y` coordinates to elements in your `data` array, which then can be accessed via:

```
  imgs
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.x})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.y})
```

You'll need to call these lines at every `"tick"` event, that is every time the coordinates get updated.